# Form doesn't do what I intend him to

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, foreach

This is my working code that - *Every time I click a marker, it shows corresponding form that its holding.*
**CODE A**

```
 For Each elem In aList
                If item.ToolTipText = elem.MarkerName Then

                    Dim camera = markerDtable.Select("MarkerName =" & " '" & elem.MarkerName & "'")(0)("cameraID")
                    Dim host = markerDtable.Select("MarkerName =" & " '" & elem.MarkerName & "'")(0)("HostAddress")       

                    With f
                        .Show()
                        .AxXHDec1.Camera = camera
                        .AxXHDec1.Host = host
                        .AxXHDec1.Play = 1
                        Dim p As New Point
                        p = item.LocalPosition + New Point(45, 68)
                        .Location = p
                        .Text = elem.MarkerName
                    End With
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
```

That's the code where I based this second one, same procedure though not a marker, but a button.
**CODE B**

```
For Each btn In bList
        Dim fcb As New Fcamera4Building
        Dim word() As String = btn.Name.Split("m"c)
        With fcb
            .Show()
            .AxXHDec1.Camera = word(1)
            .AxXHDec1.Host = 'get corresponding HostAddress depending on what buttonName'
            .AxXHDec1.Play = 1
            Dim p As New Point
            p = btn.Location + New Point(70, 160)
            .Location = p
        End With
        Exit Sub
    Next
```

I think I did what I should be doing, but, the CODE B is showing the same form. I have two buttons (from database loaded at start) when I click `CAM1`button, gives me camera one. But when I click `CAM3` shows the same form, and same location too.

What am I missing/doing wrong? Let me know if you need something.
**UPDATE:** it seems that the `word()` is not registering 3. Either I click, its value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your camera names are "CAM1", "CAM2", it might be worth changing:

```
Dim word() As String = btn.Name.Split("m"c)
```

to:

```
Dim word() As String = btn.Name.ToLower.Split("m"c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub nBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Button, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    For Each btn In b2List
        If sender.Text = btn Then ' This will check the same name so it will distinguish which form will be shown.
            ' do code
```